# TopicExchanger not sending to all queues

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

In my RabbitMQ, I have an topic exchanger called `room-topic-exchange` and the bindings are like this
[image]

When I send a message to an specific queue, using the exchanger, everything works fine. I'm sending as follow:

```
template.convertAndSend(ROOM_TOPIC_EXCHANGE, roomId, message);
```

but when I try to send to ALL queues, nothing happens. I'm trying as this

```
template.convertAndSend(ROOM_TOPIC_EXCHANGE, "room*", message);
```

I declared the exchanger and the bind as follow

```
TopicExchange allRooms = new TopicExchange(ROOM_TOPIC_EXCHANGE, false, true);
admin.declareExchange(allRooms);
admin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(q).to(allRooms).with(roomId));
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I read the documentantion, and tried with routing key `room#` too and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic exchange doesn't work that way; you bind with wildcards, you don't use a wildcard in the routing key.

A queue bound with `room.*` will get messages sent to `room.123` or `room.124`.

You can achieve what you want by adding a second binding to each room, say `room.splat`; then sending to `room.splat` will go to both queues.

Or, you can add a second `fanout` exchange. Bind both queues to both exchanges (no routing key needed for the fanout) and send broadcasts to the fanout exchange and directed messages to the topic.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, @Gary

Comment: Another question, this second bind should be a direct or can be a topic?

Comment: The simplest is 2 exchanges; the one you have and a second `fanout` exchange `bind(q123).to(roomTopicExchange).with("room.123")` and `bind(q123).to(allRoomsFanout)`. Same for the other queue; then `convertAndSend(ROOM_TOPIC, roomid, message` and `convertAndSend(ROOM_FANOUT, "", message)`.